# Detecting bluetooth connection parameters update request

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

We have a bluetooth controller to which our iOS app connects. Controller is supposed to set parameters for connection (interval, latency, ...). On Android app, those parameters are taken into account, but for some reason iOS app keeps ignoring them and uses its default parameters.

Is there any way I could catch these request programatically just to debug what is going on?